# EDI conversion using mule

Tags: mule

I would like to know if there is a way to convert EDI files to other format in mule. I have a requirement to convert from EDI to XML . I am able to do it using smooks plugin withing Mule. Wondering if there is more cleaner way to do it inside Mule, something like using datamapper. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the smooks comunity extension looks pretty much abandoned, however you could easily transform using a Java transformer like this:

```
public abstract class EdiSmooksTransformer extends AbstractTransformer 
{
    private Smooks smooks; 

    public EdiSmooksTransformer() throws IOException, SAXException 
    {
        smooks = new Smooks();
        smooks.setReaderConfig(new EDIReaderConfigurator("MY_EDI_CONFIG_FILE_PATH_HERE"));
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doTransform(Object src, String enc) throws TransformerException 
    {
        StringResult stringResult = new StringResult();
        smooks.filterSource(new StreamSource((BufferedReader) src), stringResult);
        return stringResult.getResult();
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, I have used the same from Mule. Was looking for more direct ways.

Comment: Hi Aditya, did you get any better way to convert EDI to XML in mule . Can you post the soluation or work around your using.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no visual way of using smoooks in Mule.